# C++ Partition Integers when Pivot is Duplicated

Tags: c++, quicksort, partitioning

**Updated:**

I was originally to find a partition algorithm to partition an array, as a part of quick sort algorithm.

Such as an array like:

> [5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1]

based on pivot of 3, to

> [smaller than 3 || 3, 3, larger than 3]

Finally find out that it is not necessary to get the partition above, the result below will also make quick sort work:

> [smaller than 3 || 3, larger or equal than 3]

which means 3 need not be next to each other.

And my code is below (

```
int partition(std::vector<int>& v, int pivot)
{
  int left = 0;
  int right = v.size()-1;
  while (left != right)
  {
    while (v[left] < pivot) ++left;
    while (pivot < v[right]) --right;
    swap(v[left], v[right]);
  }
  return left;
}
```

Ben notes that I should update one criteria with equal, so that one criteria is '<' and the other is '>=', this would make the condition complete.

However, the partition of

> 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1

based on pivot 3, would be

> < 3 || 3, 4, 3, 5

And and threes are not adjacent.

The real nice thing comes out, it actually does not matter whether threes are adjacent. Because after carefully think about the quick sort algorithm, this partition will finally make array sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Change one of your operators to be `<=`, instead of `<`.

```
while (v[left] < pivot) ++left;
while (pivot <= v[right]) --right;
```

This way, every number fits one of the two criteria. Either it is less than the pivot, and it moves to the left, or pivot is less than or equal to it, and it moves to the right. There is no middle ground.

For a generalized comparison functor, you can simply swap the parameters and invert the result to get the same effect:

```
while ( compare(v[left], pivot) ) ++left;
while ( !compare(v[right], pivot) ) --right;
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin, you are correct about the no middle ground, but if partition `1 4 3 5 4 6` (based on pivot of 4) will result `1 3 4 5 4 6`, because the right cursor will just pass the "second 4", leaving 5 in the middle of 4. Maybe my code will be reconstructed to do the partition, but there must exist a way to do this partition...right...thank you!

Comment: Hi Ben, the number equal to pivot does not need to adjacent for quick sort algorithm. Thank you for pointing out changing one of the operators!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

std::vector<int>::size_type partition( std::vector<int> &v, int pivot )
{
    std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0, j = v.size();

    while ( i != j )
    {
        while ( i != j && v[i] < pivot ) i++;
        while ( i != j && !( v[--j] < pivot ) );
        if ( i != j ) std::swap( v[i++], v[j] );
    }

    return i;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6 };

    std::vector<int>::size_type n = partition( v, 4 );

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = n; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 3 
4 5 4 6
```

Comment: Vlad, I need the output to be 1 3 | 4 4 5 6, is that possible?

Comment: @Vindicate It is simply a sorted sequence. In this case what is the meaning of specifying a pivot?

Comment: H Vald, sorry about the example. Let's say partition `3 4 1 6 4 5` would result `3 1 | 4 4 6 5`, just making sure the left side is smaller, the right side is larger, and number equal to pivot are together. Thanks!

Comment: @Vindicate In this case it seems you need to split the sequence into three partitions.

Comment: I finally find out that the number equal to pivot not need to be adjacent for quick sort algorithm. All right, I should mention that I write this partition for quick sort, so that you may point out my wrong. And your partition code is nice for quick sort algorithm!

Comment: And I edited my question, to make it more clear. Thank you a lot for your time here

Comment: @Vindicate At least it correctly splits a sequence into two partitions.